# Solution to $y' = (y \log y) / x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Having problems with this differential question... I know that it should be dy/(y log y)/x but I'm not terribly sure.

If $y' = \dfrac{y \log y}{x}$ and $y(1) = 2$, then find $y(5)$.

Answer (score 1):

This differential equation is separable.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y\log y}x$$
$$\frac{dy}{y\log y}=\frac{dx}x$$

Now just integrate both sides.

Comment: So dx/ln(y) = dx?

Comment: Once you integrate, there shouldn't be d anything.  The right side is $\ln x+ C$.  Is that log supposed to be a common log?

Answer (score 1):

This equation is separable:
$$
\int_2^{y(5)} \frac{d y}{y \log y} = \int_1^5 \frac{d x}{x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Mike's hint,You can have
$\dfrac {dy}{y \log y}=\dfrac {dx}{x} \implies \int \frac{d(\log y)}{\log y}=\int \dfrac {dx}{x} +C \implies \log |\log y|=\log x +\log C_1 \implies \log y=C_1x$ where $C=\log C_1.$ Now use the initial condition to find the value of $C_1.$

**EDIT:** Since $C_1=\log 2,$ so $\log y=x \log 2.$ Now for $x=5, \log y=5 \log 2 \implies  \log y=\log 2^5 \implies y=2^5=32.$ so $y(5)=32.$

Comment: Log 2 is 0.3, but where do I go from there? What am I moving around?

Comment: @DanielvanderMerwe look my edited answer.